# How to choose the weights for a linear combination of heuristic functions?

Tags: search, minimax, heuristics, alpha-beta-pruning, expectiminimax

I need to write a minimax algorithm with alpha-beta pruning in limited time for the [2048 game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2048_(video_game)). I know expectimax is better for this work.

Assume I wrote different heuristic functions. If I want to write an evaluation function as a linear combination of these heuristic functions, do I have to give random weights, or can I calculate the optimal weights with some optimization algorithm?

Comment: What do you mean by "for good enough" in "can I calculate these weights for enough good with some algorithm?"?

Comment: I meant for a linear combination like evaluation(s) = x1.f1(s) + x2.f2(s). Assume I choose x1 and x2 as 1 and 5. And with this weights my algorithm's succes chance is %50 and if I increase value of x1 algorithm's chance will increase. What if I have 20 weight? Is there a algorithm gonna find approximate weight? I heard a algorithm called CMA-ES. I'll look at it.

Comment: Well, take a look at this duuh.